# Surprising behaviour of Python date and timedelta subtraction

Tags: python, date, timedelta

I am trying to do some Python *date* and *timedelta* maths and stumbled upon this.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.date(2000, 4, 20)
>>> td = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> dt - td
datetime.date(2000, 4, 19)
>>> -(td) + dt
datetime.date(2000, 4, 19)
>>> dt - td == dt + (-td)
True
```

So far so good, but when the *timedelta* also includes some hours it gets interesting.

```
>>> td = datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=1)
>>> dt - td
datetime.date(2000, 4, 19)
>>> -(td) + dt
datetime.date(2000, 4, 18)
```

or in a comparison:

```
>>> dt - td == dt + (-td)
False
```

I would have expected that *a - b == a + (-b)*, but this doesn't seem to work for *date* and *timedelta*. As far as I was able to track that down, this happens because adding/subtracting *date* and *timedelta* only considers the days field of *timedelta*, which is probably correct. However negating a *timedelta* considers all fields and may change the days field as well.

```
>>> -datetime.timedelta(days=1)
datetime.timedelta(-1)
>>> -datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=1)
datetime.timedelta(-2, 82800)
```

As can be seen in the second example, days=-2 after the negation, and therefore *date + timedelta* will actually subtract 2 days.

Should this be considered a bug in the python *datetime* module? Or is this rather some 'normal' behaviour which needs to be taken into account when doing things like that?

Internally the *datetime* module creates a new *timedelta*, with just the days field of the original *timedelta* object passed in, when subtracting a *timedelta* to a *date* object. Which equates to following, code that seems to be quite odd.

```
>>> dt + datetime.timedelta(-(-(-dt).days))
datetime.date(2000, 4, 18)
```

I can't really sea a reason for just using the negated days field when doing *date - timedelta* subtractions.

**Edit:**

Here is the relevant code path in python *datetime* module:

```
class date:

    ...

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """Subtract two dates, or a date and a timedelta."""
        if isinstance(other, timedelta):
           return self + timedelta(-other.days)
        ...
```

If it would just pass on *-other* then the condition *a - b == a + (-b)* would hold true. (It would change current behaviour though).

```
class date:

    ...

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """Subtract two dates, or a date and a timedelta."""
        if isinstance(other, timedelta):
           return self - other  # timedelta.__rsub__ would take care of negating other
        ...
```

Comment: I think it's worth asking what it means to add/subtract _hours_ to a `date`.  If the hours are 24, then it's pretty easy to decide that you're supposed to add 1 day.  If it's less than 24 hours, do you upgrade the result to a `datetime` when you started with a `date`, or do you keep working with `date` and truncate?

Comment: Yes, that is a good question, and one that can't be answered easily. But what I wanted to highlight is, that normal maths operation like *a - b == a + (-b)* do not work as expected.

Comment: Yes, fixed that. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Should this be considered a bug in the python datetime module? Or is
>   this rather some 'normal' behaviour which needs to be taken into
>   account when doing things like that?

No, this should not be considered a bug. A `date` does not track its state in terms of hours, minutes, and seconds, which is what would be needed for it to behave in the way you suggest it ought to.

I would consider the code you've presented to be a bug: the programmer is using the wrong datatype for the work they're trying to accomplish. If you want to keep track of time in days, hours, minutes and seconds, then you need a `datetime` object. (which will happily provide you with a `date` once you've done all of the arithmetic you care to do)

Comment: Agreed. However using datetime will be a hard option. Which time of the day should you pick? (There are many discussions about this here on Stack Overflow). Maybe date/timedelta operations should throw an error if anything but days (in timedalta) is non zero? It is using a wrong type after all.

Comment: I agree that it's hard, but hard in the sense of "you have to figure out what you really mean", not hard in the sense of "it's behaving incorrectly". If you're subtracting times from dates, you really do need to tell me what time you're starting from on that date.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way how *negative* `timedelta`s are represented.

```
import datetime
td = datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=1)
print (td.days, td.seconds)
# prints 1 3600
minus_td = -td
print (minus_td.days, minus_td.seconds)
# prints -2 82800
```

I hope you now better understand why `days` were affected.

Seconds in a `timedelta` are always normalized to a positive amount between 0 and 86399:

```
>>> print (datetime.timedelta(seconds=-10).seconds)
86390
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the issue doesn't seem to be about whether the `timedelta` is negative or positive. Note that when the minuend is a `datetime` instead of a `date`, `timedelta` arithmetic works as expected with both positive and negative values, and the unexpected behavior is observed when `timedelta`s of positive and negative value are added to or subtracted from `date`s.

Comment: This answer adds some clarity why it happens, but it also suggests that the datetime.timedelta implementation is the cause for this unforeseen behaviour.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: as you rightly mentioned, a semantic type mismatch, together with duck typing and (likely) backwards compatibility considerations leads to `date` objects accepting `timedelta` with non-zero time, and unexpected results. By the same token, `1 < '1'` in Python 2. Python 3 somehow alleviates this, and `1 < '1'` becomes a `TypeError`;  the `date` and `timedelta` behavior remains the same, though.